# Python 3.9 Watchdog, start process for each event

Tags: python, multiprocessing, watchdog

I have a written some python classes to process files when they are created using pythons watchdog module.
Whenever a new file event is triggered, a process should be started to handle the processing of the file. There are incoming files from different sources at the same time, so I would expect multiple processes handling some files "simultaneously".

According to syslog only one process is created, so no multiprocessing. I only see a line like

```
Sep 21 13:53:02 host1 python3.9[6704] : ...
```

Having the exactly same PID (in this case 6704) in the log.

Can anybody give me a hint what I am doing wrong here?

Content of **fileMonitor.py**:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
from watchdog.events import RegexMatchingEventHandler

import converter

##
## \brief Class to handle monitored events
##
class LogFileEventHandler(RegexMatchingEventHandler):

    MONITOR_REGEX = [r'.*\.(gz|txt)$']  # watch out for new "*.gz" or "*.txt"-files only
    IGNORE_REGEX = [r'.*/archive/*']    # ignore events below path "*/archive/*"

    ###
    ### Public methods
    ###

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            regexes=self.MONITOR_REGEX,
            ignore_regexes=self.IGNORE_REGEX,
            ignore_directories=True,
            case_sensitive=False)
        self.cm = converter.ConverterManager()

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.cm.convertMemory(event.src_path)

    def on_moved(self, event):
        self.cm.convertMemory(event.dest_path)

##
## \brief Class to monitor changes in filesystem
## \note Has to use PollingObserver due to network-filesystem.
##       There is no OS-API supporting notification on network-filesystem changes.
##
class LogFileMonitor:

    ###
    ### Public methods
    ###

    def __init__(self, monitorPath):
        self.monitorPath = monitorPath                     # Path to monitor
        self.handler = LogFileEventHandler()               # Handler for events occurred
        self.observer = PollingObserver()                  # Method for monitoring

    def run(self):
        self._start()                                      # Prepare observer
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)                              # Suspend for some time
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self._stop()                                   # Terminate observer

    ###
    ### Private methods
    ###

    def _start(self):
        self.observer.schedule(                            # prepare observer
            event_handler=self.handler,
            path=self.monitorPath,
            recursive=True,
        )
        self.observer.start()                              # start observer

    def _stop(self):
        self.observer.stop()                               # stop observer
        self.observer.join()                               # wait till observer terminated
```

Content of **converter.py**

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

##
## \brief Class to analyze logger data in memory and write it to influxdb
##
class ConverterMemoryWorker:

    ###
    ### Public methods
    ###

    def __init__(self, logFile):
        self.logFile = logFile

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(30) # Do some long taking stuff here
    
##
## \brief Class to manage converter workers
##
class ConverterManager:

    ###
    ### Public methods
    ###

    def __init__(self):
        print('Created new instance of ConverterManager')

    def convertMemory(self, logFile):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor: # create a new process from pool
            executor.submit(self._task(logFile))                                # start worker-process

    ###
    ### Private methods
    ###

    def _task(self, logFile):
        converterWorker = ConverterMemoryWorker(logFile)
        converterWorker.run()
```

---

Solved!

Thank you guys for the hints, they almost solved my problem.
Actually I also need to declare the "_task"-method static to make it finally work.

Here is the modified code that works for me:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

##
## \brief Class to analyze logger data in memory and write it to influxdb
##
class ConverterMemoryWorker:

    ###
    ### Public methods
    ###

    def __init__(self, logFile):
        self.logFile = logFile

    def run(self):
        print(f'Started process for {self.logFile}')
        time.sleep(10) # Do some long taking stuff here
        print(f'Terminated process for {self.logFile}')

##
## \brief Class to manage converter workers
##
class ConverterManager:

    executor = None

    ###
    ### Public methods
    ###

    def __init__(self):
        print('Created new instance of ConverterManager')
        self.executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

    def convertMemory(self, logFile):
        self.executor.submit(self._task, logFile)                                # start worker-process

    ###
    ### Private methods
    ###
    @staticmethod
    def _task(logFile):
        converterWorker = ConverterMemoryWorker(logFile)
        converterWorker.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cm = ConverterManager()

    for i in range(30):
        cm.convertMemory(i)
```

Comment: you're calling the function then returning `None` to `executor.submit`. Also you create then destroy 4 child processes just to handle 1 task. Probably better to handle executor creation on `__init__`, then create a process to handle smooth shutdown as well. Otherwise, If you're not cpu bound, why not just use threads? `threading.Thread(target=self._task, args=(logFile)).start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    executor.submit(self._task(logFile))
```

This with statement is broadly equivalent to:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
try:
    executor.submit(self._task(logFile))
finally:
    executor.shutdown()
```

This is described in the [documentation for concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown). Since each executor has only one task submitted to it, and then it is immediately shut-down (causing the caller to block until it finishes its work) there is no opportunity for tasks to proceed concurrently.

An alternative is to create a single executor shared by all your tasks and to call `shutdown` on it at the end of your program.

---

Separate to this, when you do:

```
executor.submit(self._task(logFile))
```

...that's equivalent to:

```
result = self._task(logFile)   # result becomes None
executor.submit(None)
```

So it's actually doing the work immediately and not even submitting it to the executor.

You probably instead want to do this:

```
executor.submit(self._task, logFile)
```

...as described in the [concurrent.futures.Executor.submit documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit). You pass it the function you want the subprocess to call, and all the arguments you want it to be called with, but importantly you don't call it yourself.

Comment: Note also `self._task(logFile)` is being called, and the result passed to `submit`